# when should I run node.js with forever?

Tags: node.js, forever

I'm writing an express app in node. I'm trying to crash it but can't... whenever I throw exceptions the app is still running (even when no error handler is configured). I'm using express-resource too if that's related and also streamline.js.

When will something like [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever/) be usefull to me? Is it only in more serious crash like system out of resources?

Answer (score 0):

Forever is useful on development stage. When you hard work on youre code and don't want to handly restart node app. In production it can save your live, when you meet some unexpected error and all project crash ;)

Answer (score 0):

Installation

```
  $ [sudo] npm install forever -g
```

Note: If you are using forever programmatically you should install forever-monitor.

```
$ cd /path/to/your/project
  $ [sudo] npm install forever-monitor
```

Usage
There are two ways to use forever: through the command line or by using forever in your code. Note: If you are using forever programatically you should install forever-monitor.

Command Line Usage
You can use forever to run scripts continuously (whether it is written in node.js or not).

Example

```
forever start app.js
```